# Artful Aardvark (17.10) upgrade - issue with context menu text background color

Tags: upgrade, gui, 17.10, colors

After upgrading to Artful Aardvark (17.10), the background of text on windows and menus is rough/jagged and is the desktop color rather than the color of the surrounding dialog. How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Please see screenshots below.

Examples:

1. Desktop -> Right-Click -> Menu.

   [image: menu-context]
2. Browser-title

   [image: Browser-title]

Comment: Arc is the theme setting. I tried to play with Adwaita and Ambiance but change on the issue.

Comment: I mean tried other themes but same issue.

Comment: I tried to create a fresh VM image but same issue. There something not right about the Artful Aardvark release.

Answer (score 0):

After some messing about, I solved this by using gnome-tweak-tool to change the font anti-aliasing from Subpixel to Standard.